# jQuery Appended elements with href and javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, href

So I'm appending some elements with jQuery that contain href that calls another script when the anchor is clicked, but doesn't work; here's an example:

```
$(".un_comentario").hover(

    function () {

        $("#dedos_voto", this).append($("<span id=\"commentup\" class=\"vote_up\"><a href=\"javascript:;\" ><img src=\"/mimg/comment/csthumbup.png\" /></a><?php echo $utilchido;?></span>"));

    }

);
```

So as you can see the anchor has an href that calls another script, here's the other script:

```
$(function(){

    $("span.vote_up").click(function(){
    //get the id
    the_id = $("div.un_comentario").attr('id');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: "action=vote_up&id="+$("div.un_comentario").attr("id"),
            url: "votacomment.php",
            success: function(){alert("Gracias, el voto se ha agregado.");
                 }

        });


        });
});
```

So the script only works if the elements are in the html markup, but not if the elements are appended with jQuery.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are dynamically adding the href links to the DOM use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

```
$("span.vote_up").live('click',function(){

//rest of your logic

});
```

Answer (score 1):

The two above answers are correct, but I also recommend don't use `href=\"javascript:;\"` in the anchor, instead add a `return false;` at the end of the jQuery function.

I use this site for best practices with JavaScript http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/bestpractices/#onclick (I am directing you to the part about anchors but the whole page is worth a read)

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna use the onclick instead.

Answer (score 1):

`.live()` is long since deprecated (removed in 1.9), can we stop recommending it? The right approach is to use `.on()`, like this:

```
$("#span.vote_up").on("click", function(event){
    //do this
});
```

[jQuery documentation for .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Also, neither the `return false;` or the suggestion of `href=\"javascript:;\"` are necessarily good answers... If you don't have an appropriate href to replace (then use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent default behaviour occuring), just use a more appropriate element...

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `$("span.vote_up").live()` instead of  `$("span.vote_up").click`. This will bind the code to all span.vote_up elements which might get added to the DOM later.

I found [this](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/09/working-with-events-part-3-more-event-delegation-with-jquery) link helpful

Comment: Ok that seems to execute the script now (showing an alter to check it's working) but now it's not doing what it's supposed to do, I'm gonna check if I missed something.