# Javascript hyperlinks don't work with jQuery append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need some help pointing to the right direction. I have a jQuery code what pulls some HTML content via the `$.get` function after the page is loaded, puts them into the `$data` variable and it's appended to the `div_content`.

Everything works perfectly, except after the appending the javascript links in the original content don't work.

The code part:

```
$(document.body).ready(function() {
$.get("content1.php", {id:"1234" }, function(data) {

  // for example this is the pulled data 
  var data = '<a href="javascript:;" data-id="someotherpage.php?var1=a&amp;var2=b&amp;var3=c">link</a>'

  $('.div_content').append(data);

});
});
```

The standard  tags, without javascript aren't affected, they work fine.

I found some advices like this - [jQuery Appended elements with href and javascript doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976909/jquery-appended-elements-with-href-and-javascript-doesnt-work) - and this - [Appending a link with Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421032/appending-a-link-with-jquery) - and read the jQuery's .on() function but doesn't seem to resolve my exact problem with appending the content.

I have jQuery 1.10.1, thanks for all the inputs.

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: My guess is you need to delegate the events for the appended links. It depends on what 'doesn't work' means though

Comment: MelanciaUK, Rory: when I click on the link, nothing happens.

Comment: @Nick What should happen? The *href* attribute does not contain a real link or JS.

Comment: @Nick Do you have an event handler for the appended links?  The link in the code above wouldn't do anything.

Comment: please give more details of what you're trying to do, as far as I can see there is no javascript necessary here, you could change "data-id" to "href" and remove the existing "href" attibute.

Comment: The idea what I'd like to do is that on the pageload the above code runs, and pulls down the data: some HTML containing links, including the above JS link too. This JS link opens a fancybox via jQuery so I cannot use standard href. I believe the problem is somewhere with the appending because if the content isn't pulled with the .get() and appended but if it's simply displayed (I mean the content actually exists on the page in the HTML source), the JS link works.

Comment: I tried with a "$("#appendbutton").on("click", function(event){ - I but the pulled content still doesn't work, as nothing happens when I click on these JS links which should open a fancybox with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing what data may contain its difficult to see exactly what you're trying to achieve but I can see the fist thing you do after receiving the ajax response is overwrite the returned data which is obviously incorrect.

perhaps you meant something like this?:

```
 $.get("content1.php", {id:"1234" }, function(i,data) {
 var link = '<a href="someotherpage.php?var1='+data.var1+'&amp;var2='+data.var2+'">link</a>';
 $('.div_content').append(link);
 });
```

Comment: The pulled data is a block of text, containing for example $data = "Welcome to our hotel, we are located very close to the center. <img src="pic.jpg"> <br /> For further information, <a href="javascript:;" data-id="someotherpage.php?var1=hotel01&amp;var2=showcontactpage">click here</a> to see our contact information!"

Then the Contact page would appear in a fancybox window. If I just use a href link, then the link is a standard link, but I wouldn't want that. Sending the variables work fine, because if the above content/data is simply displayed in HTML, then the link opens the fancybox well.

Comment: @Nick the href is invalid, try `$('.div_content a).attr('href',$('.div_content a).attr('data-id));`

Comment: hmm, and where should I use it? After getting the data, or the appending?

Comment: @Nick after appending, for some reason I can't edit the last comment but i missed a " ' " after data-id and .div_content

Comment: tried that but it gives a syntax error: $('.div_content' a).attr('href', $('.div_content' a).attr('data-id')); If I'm correct, were trying to rewrite the href tag after it's loaded into the DIV?

Comment: @Nick yes, alright try wrapping it in a loop: `$('.div_content a').each(function(){$(this).attr('href',$(this).attr('data-id');});`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses and comments, mea culpa, it was my, a design error. I had to include the jquery and fancybox JS and CSS into the someotherpage.php (the data-id attribute), and now it's working.